# Best way to create a similarity matrix for given set of items with tags

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

We have data in format:

```
{
  '1': ['Lathi Charge', 'NIT', 'Nirmal Singh']
  '2': ['Kangana Ranaut', 'Hrithik Roshan']
  '3': ['Hrithik Roshan', 'mohenjo daro', 'release date'],
  '4': ['NIT', 'Placements']
  ...
}
```

Keys of dictionary are items and values are tags associated with them. Numbers of entries are around 10 million, We want to calculate similarity between each items?

One more question associated with same is if any new entry comes on run time what would be best way to calculate its similarity with existing entries.

Comment: Can you use Solr for that? Or Elastic Search?

Comment: and how do you define similarity?

Comment: Similarity  - would be "similarity scores" between items in range say 0 to 1

Comment: @Neo is that a fancy way of saying identical list elements between different dictionary keys?

Comment: So let say post processing similarity(1,4)=0.7, similarity(1,2)=0.

This is a sample data from larger dataset, actual dataset will have more number of tags, but they all data is in above format only.

Comment: @Neo and how did you come up with the 0.7? They have one term in common and in total 4 unique ones, so... Plus from what i now understand, you don't want to store the "similarity", just call it whenever you need it. Please edit your question to include this valuable info.

Comment: @kounis: 0.7 was a sample score, not an actual one, also the number of tags in actual data set would be lot more... I added a smaller data set for ease of representation

Comment: Update question with more info. and at least one sample similarity example.

Comment: As stands, question is not clear. What is the function that computes the similarity score? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one similarity score that I can think of which would reliably handle the data you're looking at (it looks like your data is similar to that which would be gathered in a corpus study where documents are represented as bags of words, each potentially containing several words not present in the other documents in the corpus): that's cosine similarity. [Here](http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/) is a pretty good explanation with some python code to go along.